# On a finite nilpotent group with a cyclic normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm reading Dummit & Foote, Sec. 6.1.

My question is the following.
If $G$ is a finite nilpotent group with a cyclic normal subgroup $N$ such that $G/N$ is also cyclic, when is $G$ abelian?

I know that dihedral groups are not abelian, and I think the question is equivalent to every Sylow subgroup being abelian.

EDIT: So, the real question is about finding all metacyclic finite p-groups that are not abelian.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please make the title more informative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rod, you are right when you say this can be brought back to every Sylow group being abelian. Since $G$ is nilpotent you can reduce to $G$ being a $p$-group. However, a counterexample is easily found, take the quaternion group $G$ of order 8, generated by $i$ and $j$ as usual. Let $N$ be the subgroup $<i>$ of index 2. $N$ satisfies your conditions but $G$ is not abelian.

Answer (score 2):

A finite nilpotent group is abelian if and only if all of its Sylow subgroups are abelian.  This is just because a finite nilpotent group is the direct product of its Sylows.

Groups *G* with normal subgroups *N* such that both *N* and *G*/N are cyclic are called [metacyclic groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/metacyclic_group).

Metacyclic *p*-groups need not be abelian: take the Sylow *p*-subgroup of the group of affine functions on $R=\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$, that is all functions $x \mapsto ax+b$ where *a*, *b* are in *R* and where the multiplicative order of *a* is a power of *p*.  This is a group of order *p*<sup>3</sup> called the [extra special group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/extraspecial_group) of exponent *p*<sup>2</sup> and order *p*<sup>3</sup>.  For *p*=2 it is also known as the dihedral group of order 8.

Metacyclic *p*-groups were classified quite a few times.  My favorites are King (1973) and Liedahl (1996). [Magma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_computer_algebra_system) has a slightly different classification available as a [database](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/672), and it was easy to write code for King and Liedahl in [GAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GAP_computer_algebra_system).

- King, Bruce W.
  "Presentations of metacyclic groups."
  Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. 8 (1973), 103–131. 
  MR[323893](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=323893)
  DOI:[10.1017/S0004972700045500](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0004972700045500)
- Liedahl, Steven.
  "Enumeration of metacyclic p-groups."
  J. Algebra 186 (1996), no. 2, 436–446.
  MR[1423270](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1423270)
  DOI:[10.1006/jabr.1996.0381](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1996.0381)